# Can Islam coexist with freedom of expression/choice?

Tags: freedom-of-belief

I’m pretty sure a lot of people know about what is happening in France.

What I wanted to know was can Islam really exist with freedom of expression/choice because for example caricatures of religion are not allowed, certain drawings ways of life etc.

With things like this in western countries it just won’t work as it will implement a more religious model which will cause an outrage and I feel like religion or Islam in general can’t coexist with this value.

Especially in the West were even law has higher value than religion I feel like if you restrict things like freedom of speech or expression due to religion it could be considered illegal or against the nations values.

Comment: Western countries do not implement Islam, so I am not sure what you want coexistence with.

Comment: I think every child or student who learns about freedom of expression also learns that my freedom of expression has limitations when it may hurt other peoples thoughts feelings and freedom/rights. This is what French people have thought my teachers! We see here a clear mismatch between slogans or definitions and reality of freedom of expression! Imam Malik long ago was asked about imposing the sunnah and discussing and refuting opponents. And he said tell the people what you know of it, but don't discuss with them. As the discussion lifts the noor of the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In each society there are people who can't lead a happy life without creating hate, riot and trouble.

### France: the freedom of expression slogan and theory vs. reality

As for details on freedom of expression its context and limitations you may refer to [this Article](https://www.equalityhumanrights.com/en/human-rights-act/article-10-freedom-expression):
As I've said in my comment we have learnt at school that ones own freedom of expression ends once one might hurt another person in his/her feelings and believes.
And the above linked article actually speaks about religious feelings and says:

> An authority may be allowed to restrict your freedom of expression if, for example, you express views that encourage racial or religious hatred.

This actually is going on in France and elsewhere without a restriction of this freedom of expression. It is rather the case that the president himself lights up the hatred against Muslims while others in the same country already lighted and still light up the hatred against north African residents (who are also Muslims) in first place.
Here the freedom of speech or expression is hardly applied in the manner described above, nor in a manner that gives both sides a chance to be heard!
There's a clear finger pointing at the bad guys, there's no neutral position of the juridical institution. There's nobody listening to the opposite view. It looks more like propaganda and a one sided opinion formation. Which hardly goes along with the freedom of speech and expression.

### Islam and living in a non-Muslim environment

In Islam a Muslim is only allowed to leave a Muslim country for certain reasons:

- Job/Business/Studies and he is expected to turn back
- If he can't lead a life as a Muslim in his homeland: No freedom of expression or oppression by the ruler or a kind of acceptable necessity (Is earning money one? I'd say not in general) etc.

The prophet () has warned people from staying in a non-Muslim environment saying:

> I am not responsible for any Muslim who stays among polytheists. They asked: Why, Messenger of Allah? He said: Their fires should not be visible to one another.
> ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/169), [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/21/67))

Note that in Islam scholars differ between a non-Muslim country that is fighting Muslims and a non-Muslim country that might be neutral or rather a friend of Muslims.
Normally staying in the first kinds of countries should be avoided by Muslims as this is not a good place to be as a Muslim.
As for the second kind we must be clear that having a residence status means that we accept the rules of the land as Allah says:

> O you who have believed, fulfill [all] contracts.  ... ([5:1](https://legacy.quran.com/5/1))

An official paper which you sign or which has been giving to you also is a kind of contract.
Note that the fiqh books about fiqh of Muslim minorities are still not well developed, because most scholars who have written on this topic themselves don't know much about the life in non-Muslim countries and rely on earlier sources about Dhimis etc. which actually is the opposite case. This again is a good reason why Muslims shouldn't stay in non-Muslim countries because Allah says about Dhimis:

> Fight those who do not believe in Allah or in the Last Day and who do not consider unlawful what Allah and His Messenger have made unlawful and who do not adopt the religion of truth from those who were given the Scripture - [fight] **until they give the jizyah willingly while they are humble**d. ([9:29](https://legacy.quran.com/9/29))

While in the given case Muslims could be regarded as the humbled ones paying taxes etc..

### Muslims and human rights

As a Muslim you should be proud to say that medival Europe would never became modern without the translation of the qur'an:

> And We have certainly honored the children of Adam and carried them on the land and sea and provided for them of the good things and preferred them over much of what We have created, with [definite] preference. ([17:70](https://legacy.quran.com/17/70))

The above verse had a huge impact on the so called humanitarian movement and based on the works of ibn Rushd and his dispute with al-Ghazaly a philosophy that lead to human rights began to spread and grow. While sadly Muslims burned down some works of ibn Rushd in the Andalus and in the middle East al-Ghazaly's works have been corrupted.

Due to the call -one could also regard it as hype from the perspective from "far away" Muslim countries- to freedom of speech and expression many Muslims and many Muslim scholars started listing verses and ahadith that might express this freedom. Among these you may find:

> There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion... ([2:256](https://legacy.quran.com/2/256))

which is often manifested as a freedom of religion while the same verse says further:

> The right course has become clear from the wrong. So whoever disbelieves in Taghut and believes in Allah has grasped the most trustworthy handhold with no break in it. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.

which indicates that yeah you may chose a religion, but only one is good for you.

In Islam you always have a choice (a freedom of expression) as long as you have not committed something in which you'll be involved with others and accused, judged, condemned  and punished there upon.
So the freedom of expression or speech in Islam has a limitation that is much stricter than that I've pointed at above.
Allah in fact tells us:

> And say, "The truth is from your Lord, so whoever wills - let him believe ... ([18:29](https://legacy.quran.com/18/29))

again please read the full verse as the freedom is expressed with certain limitations that address your mind saying: Make your choice, if you chose a) you'll get Jannah if you chose b) you will be in Jahannam.

### Can Islam coexist with freedom of expression?

Well I'll try to answer the following question: Can Islam coexist as a minority religion in a non-Muslim country that implements "freedom of expression"?

As stated above Muslims first need to follow the qur'an and Allah's shari'a if nothing hinders them from practicing their religion they *can* live *basically* anywhere.
In Islam itself especially in the bloom freedom of expression was allowed and scholars were ready to discuss anything. You may find lots of books refuting thoughts of sects and other religions, for example written by ibn Hazm, al-Ghazaly and even ibn Tayymyah. You may ask where are the books of their opponents? in fact it is hard to answer this in detail. But for example the tafssir al-Kashaf of imam az-Zamakhsari is an example of the thoughts of the Mu'atzillah and among the above authors many used to quote the statement of the opponents and answer it. So at least finding fragments of this discussion is possible, however still some works may exist (note that among thousands of works of the early days of Islam only a handful has been printed yet). Sadly at a certain level the Muslim scholars and the Muslim society reached a state of stagnation. Stagnation leads to a one sided opinion and this further leads to oppression and censorship which can clearly be concluded from the later works of Muslim scholars: writing commentaries on former commentaries or supplements or filtering positions that are no more regarded as stereotypical etc.. And actually religious institutions are rather not guided by the law of Allah than by their allegiance to the leaders which also makes the options for freely expressing ones opinion limited.

So we shouldn't wonder if many Muslims need to learn how to use and practice their rights (and duties) of freedom of speech.

It is not for me to give fatwa:
But in my humble opinion any Muslim who can't deal with freedom of speech and expression in a non-Muslim should consider leaving it.
None is allowed to kill. Because killing is a crime. Execution might not be a crime, but it requires first an accusation, a judgement, a condemnation in prior.
Secondly if Muslims reside in a country they should be connected and socially maybe even politically active or present and try to have at least a spokesman or representative. They should be independent from any external influence (neither Muslims nor non-Muslims, this is by far the main issue I do observe) and should only rely on Allah's law and consider respecting the law of the land as far as it is possible in regards of shari'a.
For the later they should appoint people who may learn the means to be a scholar who is able to give fatwa and do ijtihad as the fiqh for non-Muslim minorities is by far absent in fiqh books and needs huge developments. Note that most books on fiqh consider only the perspective of a strong Muslim country in which Muslims are a majority and non-Muslims are a minority therefore studying and interpreting the Meccan period, the situation of the Muslims who immigrated to Abyssinia should be on focus just to name examples of time periods where Muslims were a minority surrounded by non-Muslim majorities.

**Conclusion**

Mainly history show us that Islam could coexist with freedom of expression. But it needs people and minds that are ready to handle with this.
Note that in some cases specific sects had a huge influence on the ruler or society and/or could build an own state for a duration of time by convincing, influencing and gathering people. See for example the history related to the "Creation of the qur'an" in which many scholars have been arrested and tortured etc. because they refuted the opinion of a sect that had influence on the ruler in many cases scholars such al-Ghazaly had to discuss and refute oppositional views in front of an assembly. Be aware that some of these sects still exist.

On the other hand the history also showed examples of stubborn individuals such as those followers of imam Malik who attacked a-Shafi'i for him changing his mind and refuting or varying from his former position which was closer to the views of his teacher imam Malik once he settled down in Egypt.
Sadly a certain capability of dialog is missing in the Muslim ummah since the stagnation and until these days.

Answer (score 0):

If non Muslims critise Islam with pictures why should we care if we are the people who know the truth? That is their sin, we can pray for them and attempt to educate but if they do not respond that us that us on them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few passages in Gil Eaton's *Islam and the Destiny on Man* that might throw some light on this question where he touches upon the free expression in relation to the Satanic Verses affair:

> The main issue, inevitably, was that of free speech and, specifically, that of artistic expression. For reasons entirely understandable in terms of European history, this freedom is now cherished as a sacred - perhaps we should say neo-sacred - principle in Western culture. Islam was never subjected to an Inquisition or to the severe constraints imposed upon freedom of expression by the Catholic Church until recently. Muslims therefore do not understand the intensity of emotion raised by this issue.

> At the same time, Western culture cannot accommodate the Muslim belief that the word is an act; to speak, or to write is an act comparable to all other actions that we undertake every day of our lives.

> In whatever society we live in, our actions are constrained in the public interest and, in Europe and America during the present century, these constraints have multiplied so rapidly that our ancestors, even a hundred years ago, might have found life almost intolerable.

> The muslim  may then reasonably ask, how is it that we accept this vast and oppressive network of laws and regulations whilst at the same time removing all constraints from one of the most potent forms of action: the spoken or written word. A madman with a machine gun may kill a dozen people; a book may cause, if only indirectly, the death of millions quite apart friends m the innumerable souls it leads into spiritual darkness. The liberal culture of the West rejects this perspective, it has a right to do so. But it might as well recognise that this is not an irrational perspective.

I would add, that in today's world of social media, we can see much more clearly than before, how the written word is a kind of act as Eaton points out. And that it's easy to see that the discourse of disinformation may have been well inflated by this freedom of expression - got people write or whether or not they have the evidence, or the authority or the know how to say or write what they did.

He also adds:

> One often hears it said that a religious faith which cannot survive denigration or blasphemy is no faith at all and does not deserve to be protected. Leaving aside the fact that this presents a merciless face to human weakness, it entirely misses the point as *The Satanic Verses* is concerned.

> No one's faith is likely to be undermined by the book. The issue was one of insult to the Prophet. The Muslim is required to show forbearance in response to personal insults. He is not, however, expected to show equal forbearance in the face of an affront to those dear to him and cannot defend themselves. He does not have the right to ignore insults to his parents, so how should he respond to an obscene insult to one who is, in principle, dearer to him than his mother or father?

He goes on to say:

> But this affair brought to the surface an even deeper level of incomprehension. Modern Western art, particularly in the form of the novel, has become an instrument of self-exposure and, in most cases, what is exposed is inner sickness. The novelist works out his 'complexes' in writing. He exteriorises his despair and parades before the public all the elements of ugliness and disease present in his soul. Muslims can only find this unspeakably wicked if they recognise it for what it is, but for the most part they are unlikely to recognise something so alien to their faith and to their culture.

> This freedom of expression appears, from the Islamic perspective, no more than a license to vomit in public. Only a few years ago Western culture would have taken much the same view of a great deal of modern art and literature.

I would add, that this opinion has also been expressed by the American-Brazilian philosopher and sociologist, Roberto Ungar, who has stated 'Western literature has run into the sands'; in other words, it's development has reached a dead end.

My personal feeling is that this means that this really ought to be a clarion call for the West to develop a new kind of literature. There is, after all, much more to the written word than the novel. Most likely, people are working on this, and also, again most likely, in obscurity, given the high value that is still given, even now, on the 'novel' by the gate-keepers of Western culture.